# Как решить уравнение?

Tags: алгоритм, арифметика, теория-чисел

a mod x = b mod kx
a <= b - заданы, необходимо найти минимальное x и затем минимальное k, где x >= 2 и k > 1

```
a, b <= 10^10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен ни в оптимальности решения (какая уж оптимальность при переборе...), ни в правильности, но пока не предложено лучшего -

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

pair<int,int> solve(int b, int a)
{
    for(int x = 2; x <= b-a; ++x)
    {
        int c = a % x;
        for(int k = 2; k*x <= b-c; ++k)
            if ((b-c)%(k*x) == 0) return make_pair(x,k);
    }
    return make_pair(0,0);
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int b, a;
    cin >> a >> b;
    auto [x,k] = solve(b,a);
    cout << "x = " << x << "  k = " << k << "\n";
    cout << a << " % " << x << " == " << a%x << endl;
    cout << b << " % " << k*x << " == " << b%(k*x) << endl;
}
```

Comment: a = 3 b = 5, ответ по идее x = 2 k = 2,

Comment: Ну, я и не настаивал на верности решения :) Попробуйте измененный вариант.

Comment: Мда, озадачили... Для виде 4k и 4k+1 - это 2 и 4, а вот для +2 и +3... О, для 4k+2 - это 2k+1 и 4k+2, оба дают нулевые остатки. А на 4k+3 что-то ничего не придумывается :(

Answer (score 0):

найти `x` надо?

ну можно наверное пойти таким путем:

```
a = x*m + z
b = kx*n + z
```

откуда

```
a - x*m = b - kx*n
a - b = x * (m - kn)
```

и

```
x = (b - a) / (kn - m)
```

Дальше перебором натуральных коэффициентов `m, n` можно найти x, при том, что

```
kn - m < b - a
```

Это если в лоб

Comment: а что делать если a = b ?

Comment: если `a = b`, то `m = kn` и решений там море будет, потому что надо будет решать по сути задачу из серии `a = kx + z` где `z = 0..x-1`